# How to completely remove any mention of Recommended on Start "space" of Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-v23h2

I am using Windows 11 Pro (v23H2) and I mean this area, I just want to make it clear and go away without any text that reads:

> “Recommended: To show your recent files and new apps, turn them on in Settings. Launch Start Settings.”

I searched the options in the Settings, but didn't find anything useful.

[image]

Comment: You can disable the recommendation itself but you can’t regain the space. Based on the arrow what you want isn’t possible.

Comment: It's completely impossible to edit any source files to free up this space, am I understanding this correctly?
I mean to do some "customisation"

Comment: Windows is closed source. What source files would you edit exactly? You can disable the recommendations from appearing but you will be unable to adjust the layout of Settings. In other words you can only adjust what will appear not the layout of what will appear

Comment: @Ramhound okay, thank you

Comment: There are third-part Start menu replacements, such as Open Shell Menu, https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu, which allow customization. They also have the virtue of *keeping* the same interface despite MS adding new "features".

Answer (score 1):

**To hide recommended content in the Start menu :**

- Run *Settings > Personalization > Start*
- Turn the three toggles Off :

  - Show recently added apps : Recommendations for recently installed apps
  - Show most used apps (off by default): Recommendations for most
    frequently used apps
  - Show recently opened items in Start, Jump Lists, and File Explorer (on by default): Recommendations for recent documents and images.

The effect of the change is immediate.

**To reduce the size of the Recommended section**

- In addition to the above, Under "Layout" (at the top), choose
  "More pins".

This will reduce the Recommended section to the minimum possible.

Comment: As you can see in my screenshot, I have already made such a setting. I meant how to completely hide that section (any mention of it). But anyway, it might be helpful for someone to be mentioned, thanks

Comment: These are the only options that Microsoft has given us, at least for the moment. I didn't see in your screenshot that this was already done, because I have already given up on Microsoft's weird Start menu and replaced it with third-party products which are weaker on graphics but stronger on usability.